# Pieces of divergent series divertimento.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be two **decreasing** sequences of positive numbers. Assume that both $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\infty,\text{    }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n=\infty.$$

Let $I\subset\mathbb{N}$ and define $$c_n:=\begin{cases}a_n,&\text{ for }n\in I\\b_n,&\text{ for }n\notin I.\end{cases}$$

Can we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n<\infty?$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is **yes**, and the following is an example.

Let $S_{-1}=0$ and for $n\ge 0$, let 
$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n 2^{2^k}. $$
For every $n\ge 0$, let 
$$I_n=\{k\in\Bbb N: S_{n-1}<k\le S_n\}$$
and define
$$a_k=2^{-2^{2n}-n}\quad\text{and}\quad b_k=2^{-2^{2n}},\quad\text{when}\quad k\in I_{2n};$$
$$a_k=2^{-2^{2n+1}}\quad\text{and}\quad b_k=2^{-2^{2n+1}-n},\quad\text{when}\quad k\in I_{2n+1}.$$
By definition, it is easy to verify that both $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are decreasing.
Let 
$$I=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty I_{2n}.$$
Then it is easy to verify that for every $n\ge 0$,
$$\sum_{k\in I_{2n}}a_k=\sum_{k\in I_{2n+1}}b_k=2^{-n}\quad\text{and}\quad\sum_{k\in I_{2n+1}}a_k=\sum_{k\in I_{2n}}b_k=1.$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{n\in I}a_n=2,\quad \sum_{n\notin I}a_n=\infty,\quad\sum_{n\in I}b_n=\infty,\quad\sum_{n\notin I}b_n=2.$$

Comment: The phrase "it is easy to verify" is terrible.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Which one? Or both?

Comment: Always, in my opinion.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Then you may just skip this phrase in this particular case.

Comment: There is a misplaced $-$ sign in the definition of $b_k$ in the first group of chunks. How hard/easy did you find it? Would you put it in a calculus exam? I think having seen the proof of the divergence of $\sum 1/n$ should indicate them the idea.

Comment: @RGB: Yes, you are right. Thank you. Let me edit later.

Comment: @RGB: Hope there is no error now. I think this problem is neither too hard nor too easy, but maybe it is a little challenging to solve it during a calculus exam.